# Grunt Uglify - make specific file last

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

How do I setup my `gruntfile.js` to have a specific file be the last file included in uglify.  For example, I have an `autoloader.js` file that I want to be the last file included in uglify.  I have many other `.js` files so I'm dynamically combining all files in the directory.

I know if there's a file I want included first - I list it first eg:

```
files: {
    'Scripts/application.js': [
        'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
        'Scripts/assets/defaults.js',
        'Scripts/assets/api.js',
        'Scripts/assets/**/*.js'
    ]
}
```

I want to keep the dynamic grabbing of all files as we add new files regularly.  But I need my `autoloader.js` to be last.

I'm hoping there's a better way than renaming it to `zAutoLoader.js`

**NOTE**: The following does **NOT** work

```
files: {
    'Scripts/application.js': [
        'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
        'Scripts/assets/defaults.js',
        'Scripts/assets/api.js',
        'Scripts/assets/**/*.js',
        'Scripts/assets/autoloader.js
    ]
}
```

nor does

```
files: {
    'Scripts/application.js': [
        'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
        'Scripts/assets/defaults.js',
        'Scripts/assets/api.js',
        'Scripts/assets/**/*.js',
        !'Scripts/assets/autoloader.js'
        'Scripts/assets/autoloader.js'
    ]
}
```

Comment: why not create a second task and run after the first one is complete

Comment: 1. what if you put the `!autoloader` ahead of the catch all:

`files: {
    'Scripts/application.js': [
        '!Scripts/assets/autoloader.js',
        'Scripts/assets/**/*.js',
        'Scripts/assets/autoloader.js'
    ]
}`

2. ensure the `!` is inside your string path (i.e. `!file.js`)

Comment: This issue suggests you cannot control the order: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1338